# write query using Doctrine Query Builder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

i have three table Patient,Symptoms, PatientSymptoms

```
patient    Symptoms     PatientSymptoms
id name    id,name      pid,sid
```

i can write the query using sql

```
SELECT Distinct(p.id) FROM Patient p join PatientSymptoms on p.id = PatientSymptoms.patient_id join Symptoms s on   PatientSymptoms.symptom_id  = symptoms.id;
```

i tried using query builder

```
       $repo=$em->getRepository("EntityBundle:Patient");
         $query = $repo->createQueryBuilder('d');
     $query->leftjoin('d.patientSymptoms', 'r')
          ->where('r.symptoms =:name')->setParameter('id', $id);
```

but no-luck hope for help.....

my patient orm.yml

```
 oneToMany:
        symptoms:
            targetEntity: Symptoms
            mappedBy: symptom

PatientSymptoms.orm.yml
manyToOne:
    patient:
        targetEntity: Patient
        inversedBy: symptoms
        joinColumn:
            name: patient_id
            referencedColumnName: id
    symptom:
        targetEntity: Symptoms
        inversedBy: patients
        joinColumn:
            name: symptom_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

Symptoms.orm.yml

```
 oneToMany:
        patients:
            targetEntity: Patient
            mappedBy: patient
```

Comment: you should start with select function...$query->select()

Comment: @Escobear can you pls elaborate!! bcoz i already mentioned queryBuilder with parameter

Comment: Do you even have Doctrine 2 relations defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code:

```
$result = $em->getRepository('EntityBundle:Patient')
    ->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->select('DISTINCT(p.id)')
    ->innerJoin('p.PatientSymptoms','ps')
    ->innerJoin('ps.Symptoms', 's')
    ->andWhere('s.symptoms = :name')
    ->setParameter('name', $name)
    ->getArrayResult();
```

This will work assuming your entity relations are set up correctly

Comment: Sorry  after refresh my page i got    [Semantical Error] line 0, col 86 near 'ps INNER JOIN': Error: Class EntityBundle\Entity\Patient has no association named PatientSymptoms

Comment: what do you mean "not shown". What is output of ``var_dump($result)``?

Comment: pls see my previous comment !!

Comment: you need to setup your relations correctly according to this: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html and adjust entity names from my code to fit ones in your relationship mapping

Comment: ->andWhere('s.symptoms = :name') to  ->andWhere('ps.symptoms = :name') and problem solved!!